# When clicking on detect a face even witout entering url the numbers are still moving up

Tags: node.js, reactjs, clarifai

i am currenty using the Clarifai API to detect faces, i also created that whenever i detect a face the numbers are moving up
see below image[url image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIVb0.png)

however, when i click on detect, even without entering any url, the number still moves up, how can i prevent it from moving up when nothing is entered,
see my code below

FRONTEND code  App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Particles from 'react-particles-js';
import FaceRecognition from './components/FaceRecognition/FaceRecognition';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
import Signin from './components/Signin/Signin';
import Register from './components/Register/Register';
import Logo from './components/Logo/Logo';
import ImageLinkForm from './components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm';
import Rank from './components/Rank/Rank';
import './App.css';
 
const particlesOptions = {
  particles: {
    number: {
      value: 30,
      density: {
        enable: true,
        value_area: 800
      }
    }
  }
}

const initialState = {
  input: '',
  imageUrl: '',
  box: {},
  route: 'signin',
  isSignedIn: false,
  user: {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    email: '',
    entries: 0,
    joined: ''
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = initialState;
  }

  loadUser = (data) => {
    this.setState({user: {
      id: data.id,
      name: data.name,
      email: data.email,
      entries: data.entries,
      joined: data.joined
    }})
  }

  calculateFaceLocation = (data) => {
    const clarifaiFace = data.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box;
    const image = document.getElementById('inputimage');
    const width = Number(image.width);
    const height = Number(image.height);
    return {
      leftCol: clarifaiFace.left_col * width,
      topRow: clarifaiFace.top_row * height,
      rightCol: width - (clarifaiFace.right_col * width),
      bottomRow: height - (clarifaiFace.bottom_row * height)
    }
  }

  displayFaceBox = (box) => {
    this.setState({box: box});
  }

  onInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({input: event.target.value});
  }

  onButtonSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input});
      fetch('https://ancient-sea-46547.herokuapp.com/imageurl', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
          input: this.state.input
        })
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        if (response) {
          fetch('https://ancient-sea-46547.herokuapp.com/image', {
            method: 'put',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
              id: this.state.user.id
            })
          })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(count => {
              this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, { entries: count}))
            })
            .catch(console.log)

        }
        this.displayFaceBox(this.calculateFaceLocation(response))
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  onRouteChange = (route) => {
    if (route === 'signout') {
      this.setState(initialState)
    } else if (route === 'home') {
      this.setState({isSignedIn: true})
    }
    this.setState({route: route});
  }

  render() {
    const { isSignedIn, imageUrl, route, box } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
         <Particles className='particles'
          params={particlesOptions}
        />
        <Navigation isSignedIn={isSignedIn} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
        { route === 'home'
          ? <div>
              <Logo />
              <Rank
                name={this.state.user.name}
                entries={this.state.user.entries}
              />
              <ImageLinkForm
                onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
                onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit}
              />
              <FaceRecognition box={box} imageUrl={imageUrl} />
            </div>
          : (
             route === 'signin'
             ? <Signin loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
             : <Register loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
            )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

BACKEND code  image.js

```
const Clarifai = require('clarifai');

const app = new Clarifai.App({
  apiKey: '378c71a79572483d9d96c7c88cb13a7a'
});

const handleApiCall = (req, res) => {
    app.models
     .predict(Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL, req.body.input)
     .then(data => {
        res.json(data);
     })
     .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to work with API'))
}


const handleImage = (req, res, db) => {
    const { id } = req.body;
    db('users').where('id', '=', id)
    .increment('entries', 1)
    .returning('entries')
    .then(entries => {
        res.json(entries[0].entries)
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to get entries'))
  }

  module.exports = {
    handleImage,
    handleApiCall
  }
```

anything i can add to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is with how you handle state object, and not with the Clarifai API. For example, instead of directly modifying the state using this.state, try using  this.setState(). This way, when a value in the state object changes, the component will re-render, implying that the output will change according to the new values of the detected faces.

Comment: should i replace all the this.state from the onButtonSubmit function to this.setState()?

Comment: It's nice to hear that you figured it out

Answer (score -1):

i figured the issue,
My frontend logic woudlnt work because I'm  just returning a JSON object and not assigning any status code as such. So when i receive a JSON response you cannot say if(response) because in both the cases of success and failure you get a JSON and your if condition will always be true. So instead, i just wrapped the fetch call
with an if condition saying if(this.state.input) so that you handle the case where users cannot click on a button without entering an URL